# Rake command after deploy on Dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, dokku

I'm running a RoR application with dokku on production.

What is the simplest way to automate and run a `rake` to clear my cache **after every deploy**?

Answer (score 2):

For now I solved using a deploy hook plugin for Dokku: https://github.com/mlomnicki/dokku-deploy-hooks

With the installed plugin, create a file named "deploy/post-deploy" in the root of app. Inside this file just use the rake previously created.

rake file:

```
# lib/tasks/clear-cache.rake

namespace :cache do
  desc 'Clear all Cache'
  task clear: :environment do
    Rails.cache.clear
    puts "=========== > ALL CACHES WERE GONE!"
  end
end
```

post-deploy file:

```
# deploy/post-deploy

rake cache:clear
```

Now on every deploy the rake will be executed:

```
web| [12] * Preloading application
worker| Cache clear: flushing all keys
worker| Dalli::Server#connect
worker| =========== > ALL CACHES WERE GONE!
web| [12] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be run the command provided below

```
dokku run app_name rake tmp:clear
```

Comment: How to execute on every deploy?

Comment: If your deploy is manual you might have to just run this manually. Otherwise add this line to end of your deployment script.

Comment: @abhishek77in I don't want to run a rake manually on every deploy. My question is where/how to put a rake command that will be executed on deploy? I'm deploying with a simple "git push production master". Maybe add some docker options?